# Jsoup web scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to use jSoup to scrape a website that has the following.  I am very new to jSoup and am still trying to figure it out.  What I would like to do is be able to take the product name and price and put them into an excel file with the name in column A and the price in column B, the 0.00 can either be ignored or placed in column C whatever is easier.  Any help would be great and just cause I know someone will ask, this is NOT a homework assignment.
Thanks in advance I really appreciate it.

```
<tr>
        <td class="sku" width="40" align="center">AAN13097</td>
        <td class="productName" width="440"><a name="<!-- Empty field [Field4]  -->"></a> 
                                American Antler Dog Chew Large (40-60 lb Dogs)                                          </td>
        <!--<td id="weight_816">0</td>-->
        <td class="quantity" width="20" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="816:qnty" id="qnty_816" class="inputQuantity">
            <input type="checkbox" name="itemnum" value="816" id="itemnum_816" class="itemnum">
        </td>
        <!--<td class="extWeight" id="extWeight_816">0.0</td>-->
        <td width="80" align="center" id="price_816">$9.70</td>
        <td width="120" align="center" class="extPrice" id="extPrice_816">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
                                                                                                                <!-- rec 815 -->
```

```
<tr>
        <td class="sku" width="40" align="center">AAN13096</td>
        <td class="productName" width="440"><a name="<!-- Empty field [Field4]  -->"></a> 
                                American Antler Dog Chew Medium (20-40 lb Dogs)                                         </td>
        <!--<td id="weight_815">0</td>-->
        <td class="quantity" width="20" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="815:qnty" id="qnty_815" class="inputQuantity">
            <input type="checkbox" name="itemnum" value="815" id="itemnum_815" class="itemnum">
        </td>
        <!--<td class="extWeight" id="extWeight_815">0.0</td>-->
        <td width="80" align="center" id="price_815">$7.15</td>
        <td width="120" align="center" class="extPrice" id="extPrice_815">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
```

**
Would this be the table element as this is the "table" code before the list, if not what should I be looking for in the html code?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" id="orderForm" width="700">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="40px" align="center">Line</th>
<th width="420" align="center">Item description&nbsp;</th>
<th width="40px" align="center">Quantity</th>
<th width="80px" align="center">Unit Price</th>
<th width="120px" align="center">Amount</th>
</tr>
</table><div class="tableCont"><table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0"    
id="orderForm" width="700" height="350px">
<tbody>                                                                                                           
<!-- rec 1638 -->
<a name="1638"></a>
```

Comment: Web scraping may be against the terms of use of some websites. Are you sure you've got the permissions to do so?

Comment: Yes, it is a vendor that I use and they don't have a tech person so they don't have the items in a csv file to import into my order management software.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. However HTML you posted didn't contain table parent for tr, that of course must be in HTML for this code to work, otherwise Jsoup will drop tr/td elements and code won't work.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); // html attribute should contain tr elements HTML content
String productName = doc.select("tr .productName").first().text(); // Get name
Element extPriceElement = doc.select("tr td.extPrice").first();
String id = extPriceElement.id().replaceAll("extPrice_", ""); // Get id     
String productPrice = doc.select("tr #price_" + id).first().text(); // Get price
String productExtPrice = extPriceElement.text(); // Get ext price
System.out.println("Product name : " + productName);                
System.out.println("Price : " + productPrice);
System.out.println("Ext price : " + productExtPrice);
```

Comment: Would this be the table element as this is the "table" code before the list